# Groovy list shift and unshift

Tags: list, groovy

Is there really no built-in way to 'shift' and 'unshift' with lists in groovy? (something that ruby, javascript have)  For instance:

```
def list = [1,2,3,4,5]
firstElement = list.shift
println firstElement          // 1
println list                  // [2,3,4,5]

list.unshift 1
println list                  // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If no built in way, are there conventional alternatives?

Comment: when would you want this outside of a for-each loop? This seems like  Bash-ism carried over into scripting languages.

Comment: I want to treat the first element in my array differently from the rest.  In my case I have a 'table', represented as a list of lists.  The first list is my headers, and the rest is data.  I'll 'shift' the header, process those, and then process the rest of my table

Comment: Ah, is this for priming a loop such as "assume first element is the largest, and then look through the rest for a larger one" kind-of-thing?

Comment: For me it's assume the first element is 'special' (eg a header row), while the rest of the elements can be treated the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no built in shift and unshift...  Here are some options:

You could use a queue:

```
def queue = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] as Queue

def firstElement = queue.poll()

assert firstElement == 1
assert queue == [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

But adding back in with `offer` adds to the wrong end, so use `offerFirst`:

```
queue.offerFirst( 1 )
assert queue == [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Or you could use a `Stack`, but you'd need to reverse your list to get `1` as the first element off of it.

```
def stack = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].reverse() as Stack

def firstElement = stack.pop()

assert firstElement == 1
assert stack == [ 5, 4, 3, 2 ]

stack.push( 1 )
assert stack == [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
```

Or, you could go the long way round:

```
def list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

(firstElement, list) = [ list.head(), list.tail() ]

assert firstElement == 1
assert list == [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

list.add( 0, 1 )
assert list == [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Or you could add `shift` and `unshift` to the metaClass of List:

```
List.metaClass.shift = {
    delegate.remove( 0 )
}
List.metaClass.unshift = { val ->
    delegate.add( 0, val )
    delegate
}

def list = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
def firstElement = list.shift()
assert firstElement == 1
assert list == [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

list.unshift( 1 )
assert list == [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Comment: For the queue implementation you can use offerFirst.  Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: @RoyTruelove Good catch on the `offerFirst` :-D  Updated the answer with that little nugget of info :-)  Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

JRE methods `List.remove(int)` and `List.add(int, E)` are supersets of shift and unshift operations, making this trivial for groovy.  No reason to involve other classes as other people are proposing.

```
def baseList = ['one', 'two', 'three']

// Unshift operation:
baseList.add(0, 'zero')
assert  ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'] == baseList

// Shift operation
assert  'zero' == baseList.remove(0)
assert  ['one', 'two', 'three'] == baseList
```

(dummy text to satisfy stackoverflow edit)

Comment: This is a great and simple answer! Bonus for me is also that it doesn't require any change to Jenkins script security.  (whereas other classes/methods need to be allowed by an admin first, including `list.reverse()`)

Answer (score 6):

If you need to add and remove from the front, you may want to use an implementation of a Java Deque for your lists.  This data structure specifically allows efficient additions and removals from either end.

It has methods [`push()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#push%28E%29) and [`pop()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#pop%28%29) for adding and removing elements from the beginning.  [`addFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#addFirst%28E%29) and [`removeFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#removeFirst%28%29) are alternative names that do the same thing.

Example:

```
def list = new ArrayDeque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
def firstElement = list.pop()
assert firstElement == 1
list.push(0)
assert list as List == [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```